# KMM project can't compile the shared module to use in the ios project

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform

I'm trying to build the shared module in my kmm project so i can use it in the iOS project
my manager built the project with his MacBook Pro (Intel-based) and its working fine but when i try to build the shared module on my macbook m1 with gradle like this:

```
./gradlew :shared:build
```

its end with an error

```
> Task :shared:compileKotlinIos FAILED
e: Could not find "org.jetbrains.kotlin.native.platform.CoreFoundationBase" in [<PROJECT_PATH>, /Users/laloush/.konan/klib, /Users/laloush/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-aarch64-1.7.20/klib/common, /Users/laloush/.konan/kotlin-native-prebuilt-macos-aarch64-1.7.20/klib/platform/ios_x64]
```

more over when i try to rebuild the android project im getting the same error on
Task :shared:compileKotlinIos,
Task :shared:compileKotlinTvosArm64,
Task :shared:compileKotlinTvosX64

This is the shared gradle file

import Versions.ktorVersion
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.KotlinNativeTarget

```
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform")
    kotlin("native.cocoapods")
    id("kotlinx-serialization")
    id("com.android.library")
    id("com.squareup.sqldelight")
}

android {
    compileSdk = 31
    defaultConfig {
        minSdk = Versions.min_sdk
        targetSdk = Versions.target_sdk
        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
}

val ideaActive = System.getProperty("idea.active") == "true"
kotlin {

    // Targets
    android()
    // Revert to just ios() when gradle plugin can properly resolve it
    val onPhone = System.getenv("SDK_NAME")?.startsWith("iphoneos") ?: false
    if (onPhone) {
        iosArm64("ios")
    } else {
        iosX64("ios")
    }
    // TODO: Do same as with iOS?
    tvosArm64()
    tvosX64()

    version = "1.0"

    sourceSets {

        commonMain {
            dependencies {
                implementation(Deps.Coroutines.common) {
                    version { strictly(Versions.coroutines) }
                }
                implementation(Deps.SqlDelight.coroutines)
                implementation(Deps.multiplatformSettings)
                implementation(Deps.Koin.koinCore)
                implementation(Deps.stately)
                implementation(Deps.Ktor.ktorNet)
                implementation(Deps.Ktor.ktorNetTls)
                implementation(Deps.Ktor.ktorClientCore)
                implementation(Deps.Ktor.ktorClientCio)
                implementation(Deps.Ktor.ktorWebsockets)
                implementation(Deps.Ktor.ktorSerializationJson)
                implementation(Deps.Ktor.ktorClientSerialization)
                implementation(Deps.KotlinSerialization.kotlinSerialization)
                implementation(kotlin(Deps.KermitLogger.stdLib))
                implementation(Deps.KermitLogger.kermit)

            }
        }

        commonTest {
            dependencies {
                implementation(Deps.Ktor.ktorMock)
              //  implementation(Deps.KotlinSerialization.kotlinReflect)
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-common")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-annotations-common")
            }
        }

        val androidMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("reflect"))
                implementation(Deps.SqlDelight.driverAndroid)
                implementation(Deps.SqlDelight.coroutinesJvm)
                implementation(Deps.Coroutines.android)
                implementation(Deps.AndroidX.lifecycle_viewmodel)
                implementation(Deps.timber)
            }
        }

        val androidTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(Deps.KotlinTest.jvm)
                implementation(Deps.KotlinTest.junit)
            }
        }

        val iosMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(Deps.SqlDelight.driverIos)
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin:$ktorVersion")
//                implementation(Deps.Coroutines.common)
            }
        }

        val tvosArm64Main by getting
        val tvosX64Main by getting

        configure(listOf(tvosArm64Main, tvosX64Main)) {
            dependsOn(iosMain)
        }
    }

    // Configure the framework which is generated internally by cocoapods plugin
    targets.withType<KotlinNativeTarget> {
        binaries.withType<org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.mpp.Framework>().forEach {
            it.isStatic = false
            it.linkerOpts.add("-lsqlite3")
        }
    }

    cocoapods {
        summary = "Common library for VBox LiveTV"
        homepage = "https://github.com/touchlab/KaMPStarter"
    }
}

sqldelight {
    database("LiveTvDb") {
        packageName = "com.vbox.shared.database"
        schemaOutputDirectory = file("src/commonMain/sqldelight/com/vbox/shared/database")
        verifyMigrations = true
    }
}
```